# How to make the buttons change the value of a variable? Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this this code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
variableToChange = "Something else"
button = Button(root, text="change a variable", command="variableToChange=something")

print(variableToChange)
```

But the `variableTochange` remains as `"Someting else"`.
After some debugging I found out that the button is run after the function ends. I may be wrong.
Any fixes?

Comment: I know that ```command```is a string but that is to let u know that I wanna do that.

Comment: Create a function, make the variable in that function global.

Then, change the value to whatever you want. After that, add in the print statement inside the function. And remove the print at the bottom of the code

Comment: As I said I have 3 buttons in total which change the variable differently.

Comment: I need to pass args in them

Comment: Look at edited answer

Comment: "As I said I have 3 buttons in total which change the variable differently."So it's difficult to create three functions?

Comment: If you only want to change the value when click some specific button, why don't use `tkinter.Checkbutton` directly?That's could avoid using global variable.Just use the `tkinter.Stringvar`.

Comment: it worked thnx a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function to change the variable, like this -

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
variableToChange = "Something else"

def ChangeVar(string):
    global variableToChange
    variableToChange = string

def stringP():
   ChangeVar('Noice')
   print(variableToChange)

button = tkinter.Button(root, text="change a variable", command = stringP)
button.pack()
```

PS - Don't use `from tkinter import *` isn't a good idea.

Comment: You need to make the var in the function `global`, so once the function is over, the changed variable is not deleted

Comment: But the code is executed before the button is pressed.

Comment: @GjdGr8 How about now?

Comment: you missed to close the `'` at the end of the `stringP()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a function as such (maybe, I am not so good)

```
def changeVar():
    VariableToChange ="Something"
```

So the code becomes:

```
def changeVar():
    VariableToChange ="Something"
    print(VariableToChange)
from tkinter import *
Root=Tk()
VariableToChange = "Something Else"
Button = Button(text="Change the Variable",command=changeVar)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Make sure that you don't use () after the function like this

```
Button(command=changeVar())
```

This will not run as you except it
Again, don't use () when doing command=
Or it'll give error

I hope my advice is useful.

Comment: I have 2 more buttons, each change  the value of the variable differently. so the function needs an argument

Comment: If you wanna give some argument then use ```command = lambda: changeVar('change')```

Comment: Or you could make the changed var, in the function, global

Comment: The Laggy Table, Yes, maybe u need to figure that out. Cause' the variable in the function is local

Comment: I tried both, As I said in my question, the print statement  prints the variable before the user can press the button

Comment: Yeah, since the `variableToChange` outside the function is in the global scope, making the `variableToChange` in the function global, overwrites the other `variableToChange`

Comment: Just add in the function to print it after changing

Comment: No you din't understand. The code after the button is executed. Meaning that the print statement is printed and then the buttons become useless.

Comment: Show the output

Comment: ```Something else```

Comment: That print statement oughts to be in the function

Comment: Put the ```print``` statement in the ```changeVar()``` function that should resolve the error

Comment: Tell me if the error is resolved bro I am waiting

Comment: If u are telling in chat then I am telling u that I am new to Stack Overflow and I don't have enough reputations

Comment: Put the ```print``` statement in the ```changeVar()``` function that should resolve the error

Answer (score -1):

Tkinter.Button has the command argument which is where you can place the function to be ran.

Like so:

```
from tkinter import *

variableToChange = "Something else"

def ChangeValue():
    global variableToChange
    variableToChange = "New value"

root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text="change a variable", command=ChangeValue).pack(padx=10,pady=10)

root.mainloop()

print(variableToChange)
```

Here when you press the button the value of the variable is changed and when you close the app, the value is printed onto the terminal.

For more documentation: [Tkinter Button Command Documentation](https://www.tutorialkart.com/python/tkinter/button/command/)

Comment: You didn't use global variable, how could you change it?

Comment: if you dont say `global variableToChange` on top of your `ChangeValue()` then the assigned value will be deleted at the end of the function

Comment: and also i dont understand why you have included a button but did not `pack()` it in there, ive suggested some edits to this code

Comment: Yeah my bad. My last coding session with Tkinter and Python was from a long time ago. Thanks for clearing those points to me!